# How to update a specific row where ID, and an auto increment column are involve

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table where column 1 is `entryID` and column 2 is `ID`; I need to update a specific row.

For example I have 3 rows:

- ROW 1 contains (entryID=31, ID=28),
- ROW 2 contains (entryID=32, ID=29),
- ROW 3 contains (entryID=33, ID=28)

I need to update the row 1. How can I update that specific row?

I used the code below but I can't update row 1, but instead row 3

```
UPDATE Attendance 
SET TimeOUT = @TimeOUT,
    Time = @Time
WHERE ID = @ID 
  AND entryID = (SELECT MAX(entryID) FROM Attendance)
```

I need to update row 1 but I always update the highest `entryID` number.

Comment: `WHERE EntryID = 31` ???

Comment: entryID is an auto increment

Comment: How do you know you want to update Row 1? It looks like you want to update Row 3.

Comment: i have a textbox where i can choose what ID can i update but i cant figure it out how to update that ID where entryID is involve

example i have 5 entry where ID is 28
so entryID is incremental example (1,2,3,4,5) but all have the same ID number

Comment: ikd if you understand it. I too cant explain it clearly sorry

Comment: For example

row 1 - entryID=1, ID=28

row 2 - entryID=2, ID=29

row 3 - entryID=3, ID=30

row 4 - entryID=4, ID=28

i want to update row 1, how can i do that?

Comment: Did you try without selecting `max(entryId)`? ie, 

    UPDATE Attendance set
      TimeOUT = @TimeOUT
      , Time = @Time
    WHERE ID = @ID

Comment: You are confusing different things. You've already been told how to write the actual update statement correctly in tsql. The issue you are having resides in your application. Your code must use the value selected when creating/executing the correct tsql statement. This is the code you need to focus on. Post it if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you might be looking for something, that can be done with a `ROW_NUMBER`

Assuming your 'row number' is based on the order of value in ROW1, the following query will work for any provided row number.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  entryID, 
            id,
            TimeOUT,
            Time, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY entryID) AS RNK
    FROM Attendance
)
UPDATE CTE
SET TimeOUT = @TimeOUT, Time = @Time
WHERE RNK = 2 -- your rownumber
```

Rextester [here](https://rextester.com/TUXHJ59987)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query.

This is used to update `MAX` value of entryID.

```
 UPDATE Attendance set
      TimeOUT = @TimeOUT, Time = @Time
    WHERE ID = @ID and entryID = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(entryID) FROM Attendance)
```

This is used to update `MIN` value of entryID.

```
 UPDATE Attendance set
      TimeOUT = @TimeOUT, Time = @Time
    WHERE ID = @ID and entryID = (SELECT TOP 1 MIN(entryID) FROM Attendance)
```